# Use ClientBundle image as background-image

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm trying to use an image from a `ClientBundle` as a background-image in a UIBInder template. I used [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/ExOJAEfQmkY) as a guide, but was unable to get it to work.

In my Java class I have:

```
public static interface PriceButtonStyles extends ClientBundle
{
    String paidIcon();

    @ClientBundle.Source("paid_button_53x31.png")
    DataResource paid_buttonAsDataResource();
}

@UiField
PriceButtonStyles priceButtonStyle;
```

And then in the corresponding template file I reference it like:

```
<ui:style field="priceButtonStyle" type="com.example.client.PriceButton.PriceButtonStyles">

    @url paidIconUrl paid_buttonAsDataResource;

    .paidIcon {
        background: paidIconUrl 0 0 no-repeat;

    }
</ui:style>
```

Already at this point my IDE is showing the "paidIconUrl" string in red, indicating that something's not quite right:

[image: ide shows red]

And indeed, when I try to run it I get:

```
    ERROR: Type com.ecample.client.PriceButton.PriceButtonStyles does not extend com.google.gwt.resources.client.CssResource Element <ui:style field='priceButtonStyle' type='com.example.client.PriceButton.PriceButtonStyles'> (:7). 
ERROR: Uncaught exception escaped. com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
```

Further on in the [Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/ExOJAEfQmkY/g1CLbWvVvhIJ) it is suggested that this might work with `<ui:data>` rather than `<ui:style>`, so I tried to make that work. But it seems like you can't include both CSS styles (e.g. my `paidIcon()` method) and DataResources in `<ui:data>` resources. I wasn't able to find much documentation on `<ui:data>`, so I'm really just grasping at straws with this.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Images, where you want to set the src property, you have to set

```
<g:Image url="{res.minimize.getSafeUri.asString}" ....>
```

res is instantiated like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">

    <ui:with field="res"
        type="xxx.myRes"></ui:with>
....
```

and the client bundle looks like this:

```
package xxx;

import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ClientBundle;
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ImageResource;

public interface myRes extends ClientBundle {

    @Source("minimize.png")
    ImageResource minimize();

}
```

Creating the ClientBundle (with e.g. `GWT.<TitleBarBundle>create(myRes.class);`) wasn't necessary in my case.

Thanks for your answer Chris Boesing, but I felt like I had to share my experiences with you too.

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I do it. It is a little different than your approach but has worked great for me in this type of situation.
Your ClientBundle would look like this:

```
public static interface PriceButtonStyles extends ClientBundle
{
     @Source("PriceButtonStyles.css")
     Styles priceButtonStyles();

     @Source("paid_button_53x31.png")
     ImageResource paidButtonPNG();

     interface Styles extends CssResource {
         String buttonBackground();
     }
}
```

Then you would need the PriceButtonStyles.css from the first `@Source`:

```
.buttonBackground {
    gwt-image:'paidButtonPNG';
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Your *.ui.xml would look like this:

```
<ui:with field="res" type="com.ecample.client.PriceButton.PriceButtonStyles"></ui:with>
<g:Label styleName="{res.priceButtonStyles.buttonBackground}"><g:Label>
```

Even though your styles are in a css file it still gets minimized and obfuscated by the compiler.
**Edit: Don't forget to call

`GWT.<PriceButtonStyles> create(PriceButtonStyles.class).priceButtonStyles().ensureInjected();`
Best place for this is your EntryPoint method**

Comment: Hmm tried that, but it errors with "ERROR: Deferred binding result type 'com.example.client.PriceButton.Styles.PriceButtonStyles' should not be abstract."  At the top of my EntryPoint I'm calling GWT.<PriceButton.Styles.PriceButtonStyles> create(PriceButton.Styles.PriceButtonStyles.class).ensureInjected().I have PriceButtonStyles.css in the same package as the Java code. Also, I had to rename the upper-level interface to "Styles", since it didn't like having an embedded interface with the same name.

Comment: Sorry for given the two interfaces the same name. I think your error comes from the call to inject the style. You need to put the upper-level interface between < > and ( )

Comment: You should probably add an `@ImageOptions(repeatStyle=RepeatStyle.Both)` annotation to your `ImageResource` method to make sure the image isn't *sprited* in some browsers (namely, IE6/7)

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. The style does get applied, because if I add "border: 1px solid red;" to the .buttonBackground, I get a nice red border around the label. But the image doesn't work.

Comment: Your remark about calling ensureInjected() was very helpful!! Thanks!