# Using ClientBundle image resource in pure HTML element in UIBinder

Tags: gwt, clientbundle

Based on the following resources:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html

[Use ClientBundle image as background-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354347/use-clientbundle-image-as-background-image)

I have successfully implemented a GWT `<g:Image>` image resource in a UIBinder template:

```
<ui:with field='res' type='com._.client.resources.Resources'></ui:with>
<g:Image resource="{res.menuLogo}" altText="" styleName="{style.menuLogo}"/>
```

However, I am trying to add an image as a child element of a `<g:MenuItem>`, which in GWT can only have pure HTML elements as children:

```
<g:MenuItem>
    <img id="revealIcon" src="images/trianglebuttonWHITE-DOWN.png" width="11"/>
</g:MenuItem>
```

The image is for a small widget that will change when the sub-menu is active.

My goal is to handle all resources through a ClientBundle and avoid having any in the WAR directory.

Can I reference a ClientBundle resource for a pure HTML `<img>` image?

Should I do this programmatically and/or with CSS Image Sprites instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
<img id="revealIcon" src="{res.menuLogo.getSafeUri}" width="11"/>
```

Note that, to be safe, you should use a `DataResource` rather than an  `ImageResource` because, technically, an `ImageResource` can be bundled with other images and only represent one region of a bigger "sprited" image (in that case, the `ImageResource` will be an instance of `ImageResourcePrototype.Bundle`, but it's not possible to check it within UiBinder).